# Checking if particular node exists in Xml file using Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I would like to check is `code = "ABC"`   exists in my xml file using xPath.Can you please suggest me some methods for it?

```
<metadata>
 <codes class = "class1">
      <code code = "ABC">
            <detail "blah blah"/>
        </code>
  </codes>
  <codes class = "class2">
      <code code = "123">
            <detail "blah blah"/>
        </code>
  </codes>
 </metadata>
```

[EDIT]
I did following. It reuturns null.

```
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("//codes/code[@ code ='ABC']");
            Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println("nodes: "+ nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
            }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What have you searched for? Where exactly is your obstacle?

Comment: That's not valid xml, `<code="ABC">` is missing an attribute name

Comment: do you really have a space in your match pattern "@ code ="?  remove those extra spaces if so.  Also, the "nodeValue" of an Element is "null", so your code may actually be working.  you should print out something more meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how you tested your code because `<detail "blah blah"/>` is an incorrect xml construct it should be `<detail x="blah blah"/>` i.e. a ***name-value*** pair !!

For the XPath Expression `"//codes/code[@ code ='ABC']"` the `nodes.item(i).getNodeValue())` is going to be **`null`** because it will return an Element. See the below Javadoc comment:

[image]

***`A working sample:`***

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Document doc = getDoc();
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("//codes/code[@code ='ABC']");
        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
        System.out.println("Have I found anything? " + (nodes.getLength() > 0 ? "Yes": "No"));

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("nodes: "+ nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
        }

    }

    private static Document getDoc() 
    {
        String xml = "<metadata>"+
                 "<codes class = 'class1'>"+
                      "<code code='ABC'>"+
                            "<detail x='blah blah'/>"+
                        "</code>"+
                  "</codes>"+
                  "<codes class = 'class2'>"+
                      "<code code = '123'>"+
                            "<detail x='blah blah'/>"+
                        "</code>"+
                  "</codes>"+
                 "</metadata>";


        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
            return dom;

        }catch(Exception pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```